# Does RubyMine have TextMate-style multiple line editing?

Tags: editor, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

Is there a shortcut key for editing multiple lines in RubyMine (Windows) as you can do with TextMate? I've seen it in TextMate where you can highlight multiple lines, and press a key code, then start typing. All text you type will appear at the end of all of the highlighted lines. I would love to do this with RubyMine as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this feature is called **Column Mode** and can be enabled via **Edit** menu or keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Perfect my friend, absolutely perfect.

Comment: I suppose the only issue with this though, is that everything would have to be perfectly aligned. I wish there was a way to make it so it just added it to the end of all of the highlighted lines.

Comment: is there something similar if I want to edit two words at same time.
like - link_to 'home', home_path
now i want to edit home word in above code at the same time. What should be looking for. surely it's not column mode.

Comment: @rtdp You can use 'find and replace' tool :)

Comment: A shortcut to toggle the "Column Selection mode" in OS X is SHIFT+CMD+8

Answer (score 8):

RubyMine version 6.3 and later has real multiple line editing. Simultaneously edited areas of text need not be vertically adjacent and vertically aligned (as they must be to use Column Selection Mode).

Briefly,

- option-click (on Mac; alt-click on Windows or Linux) to create additional carets, edit as usual, then hit escape to revert to a single caret
- select some text and control-G (on Mac; alt-J on Linux and Windows) to search for the next occurrence of that text and add a caret to it
- There are also editor commands to add carets (Clone Caret Below, Clone Caret Above) that are not bound by default, but that you can bind to keys of your choice.

More here: [What’s Mining: Multiple Cursors and Selection](http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2014/03/whats-mining-multiple-cursors-and-selection/)

(Column Selection Mode still works fine for areas of text that are vertically adjacent and aligned.)

Comment: Not exactly what the OP asked for, but exactly what I wanted.

Comment: control-G is bound to `Add Selection for Next Occurrence`