# How do I add the next occurrence of the current word to the selection in RubyMine (like in Sublime Text)?

Tags: sublimetext2, rubymine

How to do the equivalent of `CMD + D` in Sublime Text with RubyMine?

e.g. `root this and that and this root.`

1. cursor on `root`
2. `CMD+D` selects both `root` (in sublime)
3. type word to replace both `root`

[image]

In RubyMine if I hold `alt` and click the word I want, it will duplicate cursors like that. That's what I want, BUT I don't want to click the next word ... I just want a NON-CLICKING keyboard shortcut like `CMD+D` in Sublime Text which is smart enough to select all of the same words.

[image]

Comment: I recently described the closest approximation that I'm aware of in an answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23846873/634576

Comment: @Dave Hey thanks... but my only option in 6.3 is to `alt+click` the next word to enable the cursor??? That can't be right... That would make me go back to sublime.. shame because RubyMine is pretty awesome otherwise..

Comment: Happily, I read the docs again and the answer you're looking for was there. See below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After selecting matching text of the first instance you want to edit, type:

- OS X: `Ctrl+G` or `Ctrl+CMD+G` (varies between installations or keymaps)
- Linux or Windows: `alt-J`

If none of those keybindings work for you, go to Preferences -> Keymap and search for the Select Next Occurrence editor command to see what it's bound to.

More here (bottom of page): http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2014/03/whats-mining-multiple-cursors-and-selection/

Comment: thanks for the assist. Same mac 10.5 but your was only doing `Ctrl+g` which toggles case on the word...